# How do I generate random numbers for that array that don't repeat? (java)

Tags: java, arrays, random

So I'm trying to make a sports game schedule generator. This randomly selects from an array that consists of field names. How do I make it so that It won't select the same field twice?

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int index, loc;
    index = rand.nextInt();
    loc = rand.nextInt(y);
    System.out.print(fields[loc]);
```

Comment: its just the variable I used. Its the random number created, so I use that to select the field name from the array. So what I need is for the number selected (index) to not be the same number twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a seperate array of the same size as your `fields` array of boolean type, then when a location is selected:

```
loc = rand.nextInt(y);
alreadySelected[loc] = true;
if(!alreadySelected[loc]) {
    System.out.print(fields[loc]);
}
```

This will make it so that if you've already been at that location, it won't print it out again.

Comment: +1 for the answer, But I guess we can use an `ArrayList` of integers and add selected index to that before which, checking if this list had the selected index already would be much more memory efficient.

Comment: A very valid point! I simply did it this way to demonstrate a potential solution at a "lower level".

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        list.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

}

Add each number in the range sequentially in a list structure using add() method of List Interface.Then use shuffle of Collections class to shuffle the list

`Collections.shuffle()` generate random number from a given list using default source of randomness.

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality. Please add an explanation of what this code does and why.

Comment: but will that select the same number twice? I would execute the code I put in more than once

Comment: It will not from given array.

Comment: you can also try to use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1)` in Java 1.7 or later

Answer (score 0):

You should store the indexes of sports in another integer from where we can check that this sport has not been chosen earlier. first store the indexes of sports in a string.

```
public void sportPicker(){
    int[] sche=new int[4];
    String[] sports={"1-Cricket","2-Hockey","3-Tennis","4-Badminton"}
    int temp;
    Random rand=new Random();
    for(int a=1;a<=sports.length();a++){
        temp=rand.nextInt(4);
        if(temp!=sche[0]||temp!=sche[1]||temp!=sche[2]||temp!=sche[3]){
            sche[a]=temp;
        }
        else a--;
    }
}
```

This would make sure that index is not there in the array sche, if it exists it would make the fuction again generate a number and check.